# Howto convert the value of a hashmap to String i Java

Tags: java, hashmap, tostring

I have a `HashMap`. I am trying to retrieve the value and print it using the key from the user-code.

The code is:

```
lib.addbook(book2.getISBN(), book2);
Book ret = lib.getbook("978-81-291-1979-7");
System.out.println(ret);
```

Current Output:

> O/P: LibraryPackage.Book@527c6768

I want the output to be a string and to display the actual value not the address of the book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to implement (and override) the `toString()` method in your `Book` class, and specify what you want the output to be. E.g.:

```
@Override
String toString()
{
  return this.author+": " + this.title;
}
```

Comment: This being Java, I think you mean `toString()`.

Comment: if his answer helped and solved your problem consider accepting his answer by clicking the little checkmark.

Comment: @DonRoby Ooops, and People say there is no difference between C# and Java ;).

Comment: @ThePadawan, ignorant people you mean. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

commons-lang has a great utility for this if you don't want to override the .toString() method, or need to represent it differently in different situations:

Here's a call to build a string based on reflection:

```
String str = ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(object);
```

In fact, this is a great way to implement the .toString() method itself.  Another alternative use of this class would be a field by field creation of the string:

```
String str = new ToStringBuilder(object)
    .append("field1", field1)
    .append("field2", field2)
    .toString();
```